# Python folder creation requires sudo to view in Nautilus

Tags: python, nautilus

When I run `os.mkdir()`, I can see the folder using `ls`, but cannot view it with regular `nautilus` (GNOME file manager, I'm running Ubuntu).  In Edit->Preferences, I checked `Show hidden and backup files`, which didn't help.

However, I discovered that I can view the Python-made folders using `sudo nautilus`.  I'm confused because this would mean Python creates folder that require root permission, but that is conflicted by the fact that I can view them using non-root `ls`.

Is it possible to make Python let me see the folder using non-root Nautilus, and why is this happening?

Code:

```
import os

os.mkdir(os.getcwd() + '/myFolder')
```

`ls -l`:

manually created folder, can view in Nautilus:

`drwxrwxr-x 3 user  user     4096 Mar 22 08:58 folder1`

Can't view.  Is it weird that it has the same file permission as the one above?  But this one was created through Python.

`drwxrwxr-x 3 user  user     4096 Mar 22 08:40 folder2`

Another one I can't view, created by root through Python

`drwxr-xr-x 3 root root    4096 Mar 22 11:41 folder3`

Parent folder:

`drwxrwxrwx 21 user user 4096 Mar 23 17:36 parentFolder`

Comment: If a python script creates files you don't own, it is obviously running as an other user (can be root, but also any other). Check who owns the process with the proper tools provided by your OS.

Comment: @KlausD. how come I can see the files using non-root `ls`?  From the same terminal session that I run `nautilus`.

Comment: @KlausD. After closer examination, it seems that only the folders require `sudo nautilus` to view, not files.

Comment: what does `ls -l` show?

Comment: ls is the list command. The -l argument shows stuff as a table, i.e. including the nice view of the file's properties. And I think that your problem is not Python related. It may be a bug in Nautilus (which happens) (btw, do you update the view before going into the folder, e.g. by pressing F5?) or a permission bug

Comment: I also assume that nautilus is to blame, perhaps some buffering that is circumvented by python's way to create the file/directory.

Comment: can you `cd` into the folder because you need execute permissions on the folder to `cd` into the folder.